# Closing DataSource if supplied to Jdbc class

Tags: java, jdbc

I need a little advise. I come to a need to close DataSource, but FluentJdbc once gets DataSource seems I do not have a way to get it back to close. Ideally I would love to wrap DataSource into try() block, but in that case connection pool is opened and instantly closed.

One way it would be to store DataSource within hash, but seems a bit overhead.

I have following code to store multiple connections:

```
public class FluentJdbcFactory {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Defrauder");
    private final static Map<String, FluentJdbc> instances = new HashMap<>();

    private static Properties get(String propertiesName) {
        try (InputStream in = FluentJdbcFactory.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertiesName)) {
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.load(in);
            return p;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static FluentJdbc getInstance(String propertiesName) {
        if (!instances.containsKey(propertiesName)) {
            HikariDataSource ds = DatasourceConfig.setup(get(propertiesName));
            instances.put(propertiesName, new FluentJdbcBuilder()
                    .connectionProvider(ds)
                    .defaultSqlHandler(() -> FluentJdbcFactory::isCriticalSqlException)
                    .build());
        }
        return instances.get(propertiesName);
    }

    public static void close() {
        instances.forEach((k,v)->v.NON_EXISTANT_CLOSE_METHOD);
    }
}
```

Anything I could so smarter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I come to a need to close `DataSource`, but `FluentJdbc` once gets `DataSource` seems I do not have a way to get it back to close.

I don't think there is a smart way to do this.  The assumption in the `FluentJdbc` API is that:

- it takes care of the lifecycle of connections, statements and result sets
- you take care of the lifecycle of the `Datasource`.

But the dumb way is pretty light-weight.  Create a class with attributes for a DataSource and a FluentJdbc, and use instances of that class as the values in your `instances` map.  Maybe 30 simple lines of code?